# Is it possible to play audio though the aux. port without starting 'x'? (pi 2b)

Tags: audio, audio-playback

Is it possible to play audio though the [/3.5mm jack/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J55VW.png) without startx?

Seems like it would be a lot of trouble just to play some audio.

Comment: When you say 'auxiliary port', are you referring to the 3.5mm jack output, or the RCA connector output?

Comment: The 3.5mm jack.

Comment: 'aplay' or 'omxplayer' will play audio from the command line...

Comment: Sorry desu, that was an either/or question. The pi has a 3.5mm jack output, which is used for audio, and it has an RCA output which is used for component video. RCA type connectors are commonly mis-named as 'auxiliary'. I suspect your question relates to trying to get audio out of the yellow RCA connector, which is not possible. Can you confirm which output socket you're referring to?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/7n2cuUs.png

Comment: @goobering, it's a Pi2B, so there's no additional RCA connector, just the 3.5 mm jack with four rings for audio and video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. I even play movies without `startx`. I personally use `omxplayer` but any command-line based player would do it.

Edit as suggested by [angussidney](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/27574/angussidney):

- What package do you need to install?

  - You need the `omxplayer` package.
- How do you install omxplayer?

  - `sudo apt-get install omxplayer`
- How do you open media files? What command do you use?

  - `omxplayer [media file name or path]`
- Do you need any special boot config?

  - No.

Comment: Could you expand on how you do this? What commands do you use? What packages do you need to install? Do you need to do any special boot config?

Comment: @angussidney -1. Tsk. No, there's nothing special about it.